# Relationship between IAM roles and RBAC in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

What is the relationship between the role my principal is using and the RBAC  in k8s?

Specifically, when I do `kubectl describe -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth` I see this role: `myAmazonEKSNodeRole` as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html#eks-launch-workers).

But when I look in the role permission in AWS IAM console, I expect to see this:

```
[jenia@archlinux ibn-battuta]$ kubectl get rolebindings -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                           ROLE                                                  AGE
kube-public   system:controller:bootstrap-signer                             Role/system:controller:bootstrap-signer               11d
kube-system   eks-vpc-resource-controller-rolebinding                        Role/eks-vpc-resource-controller-role                 11d
kube-system   eks:addon-manager                                              Role/eks:addon-manager                                11d
kube-system   eks:authenticator                                              Role/eks:authenticator                                11d
kube-system   eks:az-poller                                                  Role/eks:az-poller                                    11d
kube-system   eks:certificate-controller                                     Role/eks:certificate-controller                       11d
kube-system   eks:cloud-controller-manager:apiserver-authentication-reader   Role/extension-apiserver-authentication-reader        11d
kube-system   eks:fargate-manager                                            Role/eks:fargate-manager                              11d
kube-system   eks:k8s-metrics                                                Role/eks:k8s-metrics                                  11d
kube-system   eks:node-manager                                               Role/eks:node-manager                                 11d
kube-system   eks:service-operations                                         Role/eks:service-operations-configmaps                11d
kube-system   system::extension-apiserver-authentication-reader              Role/extension-apiserver-authentication-reader        11d
kube-system   system::leader-locking-kube-controller-manager                 Role/system::leader-locking-kube-controller-manager   11d
kube-system   system::leader-locking-kube-scheduler                          Role/system::leader-locking-kube-scheduler            11d
kube-system   system:controller:bootstrap-signer                             Role/system:controller:bootstrap-signer               11d
kube-system   system:controller:cloud-provider                               Role/system:controller:cloud-provider                 11d
kube-system   system:controller:token-cleaner                                Role/system:controller:token-cleaner                  11d
```

But instead in the IAM console I see this:

```
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings"
```

There seems to be no connection whatsoever between the permissions in the IAM console for the CLI role `myAmazonEKSNodeRole` and the RBAC in k8s. This is puzzling. How do I control which permission a specific IAM role has in my k8s cluster?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aws-auth ConfigMap maintains a mapping between IAM principles and Kubernetes RBAC groups. Granting access to EKS clusters is a multi-step process.

1. Create a cluster role or a role that defines the RBAC permissions
2. Create a cluster role binding or role binding that associates the cluster role or role with an RBAC group
3. Add an entry to the aws-auth ConfigMap that maps an IAM principle to an RBAC group, e.g. system:masters

While its possible to update the aws-auth ConfigMap manually, I recommend using eksctl or the aws-iam-authenticator instead because you're less likely to corrupt your aws-auth ConfigMap with those tools.

The role you're looking at in the AWS console is the IAM role assigned to the worker node. It needs those permissions to fetch images from ECR.

Comment: I'm not using ECR. I'll be using dockerhub but I guess it's the same idea?

Comment: how do I achieve 1 to start?

Comment: yeah, those permissions are added automatically when you use eksctl (and other tools) to provision the cluster. While Dockerhub doesn't require authentication to pull images, it will throttle you eventually. If you need to authenticate to Dockerhub, use the Kubelet Credential Provider, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-credential-provider/

Comment: There are some RBAC tools here, https://rbac.dev/

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) is: When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM principal that creates the cluster is automatically granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's role-based access control (RBAC) configuration in the Amazon EKS control plane